# Vagrant & Symfony 3.3: Failed to remove directory

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant

Trying to set up a Symfony 3.3 environment with Flex. Currently, when trying to require some packages like the following:

```
composer req annotations security orm template asset validator
```

Everything goes well, except on cache:clear I'm getting the following errors:

```
!!    [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                         
!!    Failed to remove directory "/home/vagrant/Code/multi-user-gallery-blog/var/  
!!    cache/loca~/pools": rmdir(/home/vagrant/Code/multi-user-gallery-blog/var/ca  
!!    che/loca~/pools): Directory not empty.
```

I already tried to remove the folders manually, but those are generated automatically in the installation process, and then Symfony cannot remove them.

I'm running this on Vagrant Homestead.

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: is it permission issue ? who's the owner of the cache directory ?

Comment: We have a similar issue. Are you using NFS?
Also where are you running `composer require`? On the vm directly or on your local machine?

Comment: @charj I'm doing it on the VM.

Comment: try to remove the cache directory content (from your local machine, not vagrant) `rm -rf var/cache/*` before running composer on your vagrant machine.

Comment: Can you run php bin/console cache:clear --verbose and post here the stack trace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19363) with the way Vagrant/VirtualBox maps shared folders between the host and guest machines. In Symfony projects, the cache directory is typically placed within the project directory that gets synced from the host machine.

We can [change the cache directory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir) to use a location within the guest machine's filesystem to avoid these problems by adding an override method to the *app/AppKernel.php* class:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel 
{
    ...
    public function getCacheDir() 
    {
        if ($this->environment === 'local') {
            return '/tmp/symfony/cache';
        }

        return parent::getCacheDir();
    }
}
```

The example above demonstrates how we can set a custom cache directory for local development environments while retaining the default behavior for production. */tmp/symfony/cache* is just an example. We can choose a location anywhere on the guest machine's filesystem that the application has permission to write to. Replace `'local'` with the name of the environment the project uses for development.

Comment: Will test this as soon as I'm able.

Comment: I did just like you said but I keep getting the same error, except for a different folder...

Comment: @Cláudio which folder did you use instead? Make sure it's not also inside VM synced directory.

Comment: should I run it inside or outside the VM, because the folder I used is not inside the synced folder.

Comment: @Cláudio run the command inside the VM. It's also worth mentioning that the user running the command must have permission to remove the files in the cache directory (it's possible the files were created by the webserver's user).

Comment: Oh man, this works amazingly. Thank you for this work around.

Comment: But what if have two projects, they will put their cache files on the same directory `/tmp/symfony/cache`, could this crash symfony ?

Comment: @YouneL For multiple projects in the same VM, we can change the cache path for each project (*/tmp/symfony/project_name/cache* for example). We can even tell `AppKernel` to set the path based on a config value or environment variable so we don't need to hard-code it.

Comment: One little addition to this good answer:
- use it for two envs (dev and test)
- use the same technique for the log directory to avoid any issues
- It is good for performances (https://beberlei.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html)
Code is in the answer below because code in comment have no formatting

Comment: I added this in the file src/Kernel.php inside the class Kernel extends BaseKernel and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment to the accepted answer, here is the code:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, ['dev', 'test'])) {
        return '/tmp/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, ['dev', 'test'])) {
        return '/var/log/symfony/logs';
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```